# C++ in Visual Studio Code: Include path not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio code with the extensions "C/C++ for Visual Studio Code" (ms-vscode.cpptools) for developing simple C++ programs. I have added the configuration file `cpp_properties.json` to the `.vscode` subfolder to get intellisense support (see below). Unfortunately VS code does not honor the include path defined herein. I always get green swiggles under `#include` directives saying `#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. ...`.

What's strange is, that the before mentioned error disappears when I select the correct configuration using the command `C/Cpp: Select a configuration ...`. I have to repeat this command everytime I reopen the project. So obviously the include paths seems to be correct.

Is it possible to make VS Code or the CPP extension store the active configuration? Or is it at least possible to define a default configuration?

`c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [{
            "name": "MinGW on Windows",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "${MINGW_HOME}\\include\\c++\\7.1.0",
                "${MINGW_HOME}\\include\\c++\\7.1.0\\x86_64-w64-mingw32",
                "${MINGW_HOME}\\include\\c++\\7.1.0\\backward",
                "${MINGW_HOME}\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\7.1.0\\include",
                "${MINGW_HOME}\\include",
                "${MINGW_HOME}\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "${MINGW_HOME}\\include\\c++\\7.1.0",
                    "${MINGW_HOME}\\include\\c++\\7.1.0\\x86_64-w64-mingw32",
                    "${MINGW_HOME}\\include\\c++\\7.1.0\\backward",
                    "${MINGW_HOME}\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\7.1.0\\include",
                    "${MINGW_HOME}\\include",
                    "${MINGW_HOME}\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "GCC on Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/usr/include/c++/6",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6",
                "/usr/include/c++/6/backward",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include/c++/6",
                    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6",
                    "/usr/include/c++/6/backward",
                    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed",
                    "/usr/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 2
}
```

Comment: Right click on the project (not the solution) in VS, and choose `Properties`. In the box that opens, choose `Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> General` on the left side, and update the `Additional Include Directories` entry on the right side. Make sure that you do it for All Configurations (and not only for Debug or Release or etc).

Comment: My question concerns _Visual Studio Code_ not _Visual Studio_.

Comment: I have the same issue (but selecting the configuration doesn't "fix" it). As a workaround, I had to revert the setting of intellisense to `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"` instead of `"Default"`.